# rails group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have  budgets table with emptype_id and calendar_id   actual_head, estimated_head

when i do  `Budgets.sum(:actual_head ,:group=>"emptype_id,calendar_id")`  i do not get the result grouped by the above two columns  but only by the `emptype_id`

however when i check the log  the sql query is right

```
SELECT sum(`budgets`.actual_head) AS sum_actual_head, emptype_id,calendar_id AS emptype_id_calendar_id FROM `budgets` GROUP BY emptype_id,calendar_id
```

has 103 rows

I wanted to iterate through each emptype_id and calendar_id  to get a sum of actual_head
and do some calculations on it.

Answer (score 10):

Grouping with multiple columns cannot be supported by rails. You have to use a regular find all:

```
budgets = Budgets.find(:all, 
                       :select => "emptype_id, calendar_id, sum(budgets.actual_head) AS sum_actual_head", 
                       :group => "emptype_id, calendar_id")

budgets.each { |budget| puts budget.sum_actual_head }
```

Comment: For more recent versions of rails (>=3.2) use `Budgets.select("emptype_id, calendar_id, sum(budgets.actual_head) AS sum_actual_head").group("emptype_id, calendar_id")` since find only works with ids.

Answer (score 6):

I cheat.  Do `:group => ["emptype_id,calendar_id"].`

Not want you nor I want, but this works at least.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of this, buy try `:group => [:emptype_id, :calendar_id]`

Comment: hi, that does not work throws the error below; hmm is there no way to group by two columns 


"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'emptype_idcalendar_id' in 'field list': SELECT sum(`budget
s`.actual_head) AS sum_actual_head, emptype_idcalendar_id AS emptype_idcalendar_id FROM `budgets`  GROUP BY emptype_idca
lendar_id"

Comment: This works for me with Rails 3.0.x: `Evaluation.average(:score, :group => [:person_id, :category])`.

Comment: It will trough an error. If we run this code active record will parse these column name as single word like emptype_idcalendar_id