# Rails: group by day and one other column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Visitor
  has_many :sessions
end

class Session
  belongs_to :visitor
  belongs_to :site
end

class Site
  has_many :sessions
end
```

I'd like to be able to get the number of visitors to a site for each day.  Since a visitor is not directly associated with a site, but a session is, I need to get all sessions for a particular site, group by day, then group by visitor_id.  Here's some sample data (ordered by created_at ASC):

```
visitor_id  site_id   created_at
6           3         2011-09-27
6           3         2011-09-27
7           3         2011-09-27
2           3         2011-09-29
7           3         2011-09-29
```

Ideally, I should see that on 09/27 there were 2 unique visitor, and on 09/29 there were also 2 unique visitors.  I've tried this:

```
Session.group('date(created_at)').group('visitor_id').size
```

But I get this in return (which is not correct):

```
 # => {Tue, 27 Sep 2011=>3, Thu, 29 Sep 2011=>2}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241352/rails-group-by-multiple-columns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@counts = Session.group('date(created_at), visitor_id').count

@counts.each do |(date, visitor), count|
  puts "#{visitor.name} visted the site #{count} times on #{date}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.where(:created_at => desired_date).group('visitor_id').count
```

No console to test on here, sorry.

Comment: If you want to start going by each individual site, then start using has_many :through

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.  Unfortunately, that doesn't group them by day.  I could loop through the results, and put them in their respective days, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@counts = Session.group('date(created_at)').
                  select("count(distinct sessions.visitor_id) as total, sessions.created_at").
                  all

@counts.each do |count|
  puts "#{count.total} on #{count.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%y')}"
end
```